# Extending Build Explorer within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I was wondering if there is a way to extend build explorer that displays the status of current/completed builds within Visual Studio with TFS. Basically I want to add another menu option to the context menu that pops up when someone right clicks a build (see screenshot). If someone selects this menu option I would like to load up a custom UI dialogue box.

[image: Default Options in context menu]
Alternatively if I could extend the build explorer main window itself and add another column to the right of "Requested By" column that would be great too. In this new column I would like to put in a button which then triggers a custom UI.

The best I could find so far illustrates how can you extend Team Explorer window (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/26/extend-team-projects-and-team-explorer-in-tfs-2010.aspx) but that is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) has its own Build Manager, with extended functionality from the default one. The source code is available for download, so I think you are allowed to extend that for your own purposes - as long as you follow the [licensing rules](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/license).

Comment: Thanks but I can not use that for some internal reasons. I really do need to extend the default Build Explorer Window if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that's neither possible nor allowed since it's an integral part of Visual Studio.

Comment: "So when new features are added out of band (like power tools and feature packs…more on that below), they have to be purely additive releases where they can’t change existing bits." From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/15/visual-studio-2010-how-to-extend-the-architecture-tools-2.aspx. Good enough?